# 405 error method is not allowed python django

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-405

I am working on shopping cart application in Django(Book Example). When I tried to test it via browser it is responding 405 method not allowed error. As I understand when I am sending request via form(method='post') it is sending http GET request.As I undertand, It is a reason of error(405).
Here is HTML form:

```
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" method="POST">
    {{ cart_product_form }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
</form>
```

forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1,21)]
class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES, coerce=int)
    override = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

views.py file:

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], override_quantity=cd['override'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

@require_POST
def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

@require_POST
def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

Comment: do you get error when the page is loaded for first time or when you submit the data from form?

Comment: In both cases it redirects to cart_detail view. So anyway I got this error

Answer (score 0):

remove `@require_POST` for
`cart_detail`

```
def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

and I recommend checking your entire code with Django 3 by example GitHub from this [link](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-3-by-Example)

Comment: I already tried. It occurs another error: NoReverseMatch at /cart/
Reverse for 'cart_remove' not found. 'cart_remove' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: are you added ```name='cart_detail'``` in urls.py for detail view?

Comment: and ```app_name = "cart"``` ?

Comment: Yes, sure. name, app_name. Everything.

Comment: check out the link in the awnser